# BCP issue in importing field having extended ASCII Character ñ

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, bcp

I am trying to do an BCP for a set of records in file.  It fails in the record which has extended ASCII characters.

I tried the command

```
bcp db1.table1 in  "C:\file.DAT"  -T -C ACP -SMyServer\SQL2012Instance -r"\n" -t"," -b100000 -c
```

I used the code page option as -C RAW , however it hasn't worked out.

For that Record, I am receiving the below error.  Could you please help for the format to be specified in this case.

```
SQLState = 22001, NativeError = 0 Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]String data, right truncation
```

Could you please help for the format to be specified in this case.

Comment: this issue we use to face with driver old  ODBC driver  .. update odbc driver or use ssis ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is identified and I want to update the fact that , the input file for BCP was in UTF-8 format, which is not a supported encoding by BCP utility.

Hence, I have prepared that file in Latin1Encoding(in C#) instead of UTF-8. It can still  hold the extended ascii characters in 1 byte.
Then I have changed the BCP command  to accept the code page 1252 which is for latin 1 encoding which BCP supports, which worked.  Please see the altered command below.

```
bcp db1.table1 in  "C:\file.DAT"  -T -C 1252 -SMyServer\SQL2012Instance -r"\n" -t"," -b100000 -c
```

There is also an alternate solution for this by preparing the file in Unicode Character set and can use -w option instead of -c  in the command.